# Bootstrap side menu navigation issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have totally 5 pages for my site. In that, 2 main pages have sub menus/pages.

I am using + and - icons for users to know there is sub menus in the website.

When I click on submenu li it toggles + and - icon. However, when I click on + button and again I click on second + button the previous submenu closes however the icon is not changing from - to +.

Jquery:

```
if (li.hasClass("open") && li.children("ul:visible").size()) {
        li.children("ul").slideUp().parent('li').removeClass("open");
        li.children("ul").slideUp().parent('li').children("a").children("span").removeClass("open")   ;     
    } else {
        li.children("ul").slideDown().parent('li').addClass("open");
        li.children("ul").slideDown().parent('li').children("a").children("span").addClass("open");
}
```

html page structure:

1. home
2. about
3. services
   3.1 service 1
   3.2 Service 2
4. Works
   4.1. Works1
   4.2. works 2
5. Contact

I am using bootstrap 3. Looking for side menu similar to http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/sb-admin-2/

Comment: Put a fiddle together

Comment: Post your markup or better yet set up a JSBin or Fiddle

Comment: Here is a fiddle similar to my problem.When I click on first dropdown 2 times the icon moves up and down.However, when I click on first tab icon changes and when I click on second tab previous dropdown alone closes not the icon is changing. Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/apougher/P8WRA/

Comment: Here is another exact example of my problem. http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/responsive-navigation-menu

Answer (score 0):

I made it work by controlling in CSS itself.